# What's the correct way to write an Uri to a resource inside a Silverlight Class Library

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, silverlight-4.0, uri

I have a Silverlight Business Application project. I also added a Silverlight Class Library to be used from my Silverlight app (of course).

Inside that library (let's call it helper) I have a folder and some small images. In that same library I have a child window with a Image control which I need to change the source info at runtime (code behind).

I found some code online that should work, as a matter of facts it does, when I add an internet uri, say to a flickr image. So my problem is that I'm not writing the `Uri` right :(

```
Uri uri = new Uri("MyProj.Silverlight.Helper;images/error.png",UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);
dlg.image.Source = img;
```

I feel I've already tried every possible way, obviously I haven't :(

**Edit**: I found a pretty [cool post](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2008/03/silverlight-2-demystifying-uri.html) about it, but still no luck. Has it changed since Silverlight 2?

Comment: Is MyProj.Silverlight.Helper the name of the assembly with the images? As in the blog post you linked, you will need to resolve the path to the images properly. Check the name of the assembly and also check using component like - Source=”/{assemblyShortName};component/Foo.jpg”/>

Comment: what's component? MyProject.Silverlight.Helper is the namespace (and name) of my assebly... I don't see what am I missing :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the format: `"/MyProj.Silverlight.Helper;component/images/error.png"`

The `/` at the beginning and the keyword `component` are very important!

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: yes! thank you very much... had no clue about the 'component' word